# Grabing questions from a pdf textbook?

Tags: .net, pdf, itext, pdf-reader

So I want to make a program that can give random questions from a textbook based on topic and difficulty. At the moment I am able to output the text on a page given a page number, and output the xy coordinates of a chunk of text given page number and text. The biggest problem I am facing is how I can have the program understand that a particular question is under this section of this exercise and then grab the text of that question, including more complex characters like sub/superscript, mathematical symbols other than plus, minus etc. Or if the question involves a diagram, snip the question from the pdf as an image.

As a particularly bad example, the following 2 questions:
[image: math bro]

Output as:
16. A triangle has vertices at points in the Argand diagram which represent the complex numbers z , z and z .
1 2 3
y
z -z
2 1
π π
If =cos +isin , show that the triangle is equilateral.
3 3
P
z -z
3 1
2
P
3
17. In the diagram on the right, the points P , P and P represent
1 2 3
z z
P
2 3
1
the complex numbers z , z and z respectively. If = , show
1 2 3
z z
1 2
6 O x
that OP bisects P OP .
2 1 3

This is because of two reasons, the first is that the subscript is counted as separate chunks, and the second is that the diagrams in this textbook use text on top of the image, so the p1, 2 and 3 are separate chunks.

My code uses ItextSharp primarily for everything, here is the code:

TextExtractionStrategy.vb

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser

Namespace TextExtractionStrategy

    Public Class LocationTextExtractionStrategyWithPosition
        Inherits LocationTextExtractionStrategy

        Private ReadOnly locationalResult As List(Of TextChunk) = New List(Of TextChunk)()
        Private ReadOnly tclStrat As ITextChunkLocationStrategy

        Public Sub New() 'constructors'
            Me.New(New TextChunkLocationStrategyDefaultImp())
        End Sub

        Public Sub New(ByVal strat As ITextChunkLocationStrategy)
            tclStrat = strat
        End Sub

        Private Function StartsWithSpace(ByVal str As String) As Boolean 'Logical Operators to check for spaces'
            If str.Length = 0 Then Return False
            Return str(0) = " "c
        End Function

        Private Function EndsWithSpace(ByVal str As String) As Boolean
            If str.Length = 0 Then Return False
            Return str(str.Length - 1) = " "c
        End Function

        Private Function filterTextChunks(ByVal textChunks As List(Of TextChunk), ByVal filter As ITextChunkFilter) As List(Of TextChunk)
            If filter Is Nothing Then 'does nothing if no filters are applied'
                Return textChunks
            End If

            Dim filtered = New List(Of TextChunk)()

            For Each textChunk In textChunks 'checks chunks for if they apply to filter'

                If filter.Accept(textChunk) Then
                    filtered.Add(textChunk)
                End If
            Next

            Return filtered
        End Function

        Public Overrides Sub RenderText(ByVal renderInfo As TextRenderInfo)
            Dim segment As LineSegment = renderInfo.GetBaseline()

            If renderInfo.GetRise() <> 0 Then
                Dim riseOffsetTransform As Matrix = New Matrix(0, -renderInfo.GetRise())
                segment = segment.TransformBy(riseOffsetTransform)
            End If

            Dim tc As TextChunk = New TextChunk(renderInfo.GetText(), tclStrat.CreateLocation(renderInfo, segment))
            locationalResult.Add(tc)
        End Sub

        Public Function GetLocations() As IList(Of TextLocation)
            Dim filteredTextChunks = filterTextChunks(locationalResult, Nothing)
            filteredTextChunks.Sort() 'sorts text chunks'
            Dim lastChunk As TextChunk = Nothing
            Dim textLocations = New List(Of TextLocation)()

            For Each chunk In filteredTextChunks

                If lastChunk Is Nothing Then 'add the first chunk'
                    textLocations.Add(New TextLocation With {
                        .Text = chunk.Text,
                        .X = chunk.Location.StartLocation(0),
                        .Y = chunk.Location.StartLocation(1)
                    })
                Else

                    If chunk.SameLine(lastChunk) Then 'if the chunk is on the same line as the previous chunk'
                        Dim text = "" 'clear text'
                        If IsChunkAtWordBoundary(chunk, lastChunk) AndAlso Not StartsWithSpace(chunk.Text) AndAlso Not EndsWithSpace(lastChunk.Text) Then text += " "c 'add a space if it doesnt already have one where it needs to be'
                        text += chunk.Text 'add text to space'
                        textLocations(textLocations.Count - 1).Text += text 'add text to the previous chunk'
                    Else 'otherwise the chunk is on a new line, so it can be added as a brand new chunk'
                        textLocations.Add(New TextLocation With {
                            .Text = chunk.Text,
                            .X = chunk.Location.StartLocation(0),
                            .Y = chunk.Location.StartLocation(1)
                        })
                    End If
                End If

                lastChunk = chunk
            Next

            Return textLocations
        End Function
    End Class

    Public Class TextLocation 'Custom class containing text and its xy coords'
        Public Property X As Single
        Public Property Y As Single
        Public Property Text As String
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Program.vb

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports System.Text

Namespace TextExtractionStrategy
    Module Program
        Dim PDFLocation As String = "C:\math.pdf"
        Sub Main(args As String())
            Dim codepages = CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance
            Encoding.RegisterProvider(codepages)
            ReadText()
        End Sub
        Function GetTextCoord(page As Integer, searchText As String) As List(Of TextLocation)
            Dim searchResult As List(Of TextLocation) = New List(Of TextLocation)
            Using reader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(PDFLocation)
                Dim parser = New PdfReaderContentParser(reader)
                Dim strategy = parser.ProcessContent(page, New LocationTextExtractionStrategyWithPosition())
                Dim res = strategy.GetLocations()
                reader.Close()
                Dim temp As TextLocation() = res.ToArray
                For i = 0 To temp.Length - 1
                    If temp(i).Text.Contains(searchText) Then
                        searchResult.Add(temp(i))
                    End If
                Next
            End Using
            Return searchResult
        End Function
        Sub ReadText()
            Using reader As PdfReader = New PdfReader("C:\math.pdf")
                Dim text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, 46)
                reader.Close()
                Console.WriteLine(text)
            End Using
        End Sub
    End Module
End Namespace
```

You should need the iTextSharp and System.Text.Encoding.CodePages packages, the link to the pdf textbook I am using is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kfSFHexMqO9SLN3fDRPWXY6ypJEoXGqF/view?usp=sharing
Put the file in your C drive and in no folders, such that the file path is C:\math.pdf

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you might try to use [pdftotext](https://www.xpdfreader.com/pdftotext-man.html) to extract the text from your `.pdf` file. Then scan the resulting text file to get the question sections.

If the math parts are stored as graphics, you are out of luck.

Comment: “If the math parts are stored as graphics, your out of luck” Not really because I am able to snip images from the textbook given the text so if I am able to find the difference between questions, I can get the position of one question and the next, and use that as a range for the program to snip.